# Cisco log: mac address table full, mac overload

Tags: cisco, mac

I'm currently searching the corresponding messages in a sh log on cisco to the situation when the mac-address-table is full or overloaded. I found a lot about port-security but nothing to the simple message output (target platform = generic Catalyst switches).

As I guess a lot of you guys will know this, I found it would be faster to ask here.
On Cisco 6500 Nexus, I found that a mac address overload situation is when your switch mac table can fill in fast enough regarding the quantity of incoming new mac-addr (doesn't mean it's full). I don't know if this exist on a classic Catalyst switch.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if a catalyst switch can have its mac table overloaded, the answer is yes.  There's a finite storage space.